# Multiple queries to CompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch, and coding my first chunk job.

What I want to do in my chunk program is...

- ItemReader: 
  Read 1 tsv file. [Done]
- ItemProcessor: 
  Compose 2 queries (insert or update) with different binds and conditions dynamically, depends on item fields' value.[Done]
  Save the query to HashMap(code, query) in StepExecutionContext. [Done]
- CompositeItemWriter:
  Delegate 2 JdbcBatchItemWriters. (write all records to 2 tables)  [Done]
  Get the right queries for each tables by code from StepExecutionContext,
  and pass it to each writers. [Problem!]

I found "ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" examples, but only for 1 writer. 
Are there any good solutions to pass multiple queries to both JdbcBatchItemWriters?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You probably need a custom item writer.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for your comment! I will check about custom item writers.

Comment: I've managed this requirement by CustomItemWriter! Thank you.